# Programa em Python para calcular uma série

Tags: python-3.x

Dado n, imprimir o valor de

```
Sn = 1/n + 2/(n-1) + 3/(n-2) + ... + n.
```

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
n =2
soma =1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n>i:        
        soma+=i/n + i/(n-1)
```

Mas só funciona quando n=2. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Me desculpe a ignorância, mas essa sequencia está estranha. Ela implica que os valores irão eventualmente convergir em `n`, mas na verdade eles irão convergir em `n+1/(n-n)`, no qual você terá um erro de divisão por 0. Essa sequencia está certa?

Comment: @Andre  retirei de um exercício;  https://www.ime.usp.br/~cris/aulas/08_1_110/abril.html

Comment: @Andre  retirei de um exercício - Problema 10.1:;  https://www.ime.usp.br/~cris/aulas/08_1_110/abril.html

Comment: Bom, no próprio exercício tem um exemplo de implementação em C, que convertido para Python ficaria [dessa forma](https://ideone.com/IS6pZY), acho que você pode usar como referência, é o seu laço `for` que está fazendo coisa a mais.

Comment: @Andre nao entendi o (i+1)/(n-i)

Comment: É o termo geral da sua série

Comment: @Woss realmente nao entendi como se chegou a este termo geral

Comment: Termo geral é a fórmula para o elemento da posição `i`, ou seja: `soma = 0   for i in range(n): soma += (i + 1) / (n - i)` - ou ainda `soma = sum((i + 1) / (n - i) for i in range(n))`